# Area under staircase walk

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk

If I create a random lattice path from $(0,0)$ to $(n,k)$, taking only north or east steps $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$, with equal probability, the so called staircase walk, what are the moments of the area under the walk, that is between the walk and the $x$-axis?

Comment: do you mean the average area over all such paths?

Comment: the expectation is $\frac{1}{2} n k$, but what about the variance, skewness etc?

Comment: If you want your random walk to end at $(n,k)$, then that puts constraints on what steps you will be able to take - once you hit a boundary ($x = n$ or $y = k$), your steps will be forced.

For example, if $k = o(n)$, then you will hit the $y = k$ boundary quite early on, and then have a rectangle of length $(1- o(1))n$ and height $k$, so the expected area is $(1 - o(1))nk$.

In your probability space, do you want to select a lattice path uniformly at random?

Comment: Yes, select a path uniformly at random. Sorry this was not clear.